# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-2.0, django-queryset

Estou tentando editar um objeto mas não estou conseguindo instanciar pelo filtro de id desejado para mostrar no meu form e editar.

Django 2.1.15
Python 3.8.1

meu views.py

```
def Alterar_Pessoa(request, id):
    visitantes = get_list_or_404(DadosPessoas, id=id)
    form = PessoaForm(instance=visitantes)

    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        form = PessoaForm(request.POST, instance=visitantes)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            form.save()
            return redirect('cadastroPessoa')
    context = {
        'forms': form,
        'visitantes': visitantes,
    }
    return render(request, 'portaria/cadastroPessoa.html', context)
```

trecho do template que carrega o form e faz o request cadastroPessoa.html

```
{% for visitante in visitantes %}
      <tr>
         <td><a href="#">{{visitante.nome}}</a></td>
         <td>{{visitante.empresa}}</td>
         <td>{{visitante.tipo}}</td>

          <td><a type="button" class="btn mb-1 btn-danger"
           style="position: relative;"href="excluirPessoa/{{visitante.id}}">Excluir<span class="btn-icon-right"><i
                                                            class="fa fa-close"></i></span>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a style="color: white;" type="button" href="alterarPessoa/{{visitante.id}}"
                                                        class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary"
                                                        style="position: absolute;">Editar<span
                                                            class="btn-icon-right"><i class="icon-note"></i></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                        </td>


                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from portaria import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Pagina_Login, name='paginaLogin'),
    path('mcs/home', include('portaria.urls')),
    path('portaria/cadastroPessoa', views.Cadastro_Pessoa, name="cadastroPessoa"), 
    path('portaria/cadastroVeiculo', views.Cadastro_Veiculo, name="cadastroVeiculo"),
    path('portaria/cadastroCredencial', views.Cadastro_Credencial, name="cadastroCredencial"),
    path('portaria/movi-Entrada', views.Movi_Entrada, name="movi-Entrada"), 
    path('portaria/telaBloqueio', views.Tela_Bloqueio, name='telaBloqueio'),
    path('portaria/excluirPessoa/<int:id>', views.Excluir_Pessoa, name="excluirPessoa"),
    path('portaria/alterarPessoa/<int:id>', views.Alterar_Pessoa, name="alterarPessoa"),
]
```

Traceback do erro

> File
>   "C:\Users\loliveira.JSP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\loliveira.JSP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\loliveira.JSP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 124, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\loliveira.JSP\Desktop\projetojsp\MCS\MCS_Back\portaria\views.py",
>   line 29, in Alterar_Pessoa
>       form = PessoaForm(instance=visitantes)   File "C:\Users\loliveira.JSP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py",
>   line 292, in **init**
>       object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)   File
>   "C:\Users\loliveira.JSP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py",
>   line 82, in model_to_dict
>       opts = instance._meta AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta' [23/Apr/2020 11:33:49] "GET
>   /portaria/alterarPessoa/5 HTTP/1.1" 500 78437

Obs: Usei a mesma estrutura porém usando o get_objects_or_404(Model, id=id) anteriormente mas não dava o erro de 'model' objects is not iterable, e esse metodo de get funcionou normalmente ao excluir um registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando alterar um objeto só, de uma pessoa, mas está pesquisando uma lista vinda do banco:

```
visitantes = get_list_or_404(DadosPessoas, id=id)
```

Pela [documentação do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404), o método `get_list_or_404()` retorna uma lista de resultados. Para retornar apenas o resultado correspondente ao objeto com o id especificado, use o método `get_object_or_404` [(mais sobre ele aqui)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

```
visitantes = get_object_or_404(DadosPessoas, id=id)
```

Comment: Eu tentei usar o get_object_or_404 também, porém me trouxe um erro de iteração dizendo que o objeto não é iteravel, foi após receber este erro que me sugeriram utilizar o list .